# How to create a custom menu for specific user

Tags: customization, menus, add-menu-page

Hi it is a way to create custom menus for each user and user roles.

Each user needs to have specific page.

Comment: Are you asking for custom menus in the back end or on the front end? And can you clarify your page question - what type of specific page do you mean, within the back end or front end?

Comment: For the Front End and is a custom page also in the front end, so each user need to have a custom menu so they can see that specific page for that user.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. There are many ways to create a page for each user - one example would be to create a custom post type for each, so they can only edit that page. It just depends on what your needs are, whether the users should be able to edit the page, how exactly you want to link them to this page, etc.